# Why is req.body undefined?

Tags: node.js, request, postman

This is my code

```
app.post("/hi",(req, res)=>{
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().min(2).required()
    });
    const result=schema.validate(req.body);
    if(result.error){
        res.status(400).send(result.error);
        return;
    }
    console.log(req.body);


    
});

const port=process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("listening on port "+port );

    
});
```

It just listens on the localhost on port 3000 and logs the body of the request into the console. When I send any request through Postman, it works fine except it outputs "undefined". Why is this? Is this a problem with my code or with my usage of Postman?

Comment: Not all "requests" necessarily *HAVE* a "body": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages

Comment: i clearly put a body when doing my request on postman

Comment: are you using any middleware? maybe body-parser?

Comment: no i am not using one

Answer (score 17):

Express, by default, does not read the body of a POST request (or any request for that matter).  So, you have to install some software (usually middleware) that recognizes the particular content-type of the incoming request body, reads the body from the incoming stream, parses it and places the result where you expect it (usually `req.body`).

If you don't have any such middleware, then `req.body` will be empty and the body of the request will remain in the incoming stream, not read by Express.  Eventually, it will get thrown away when you terminate your request or when the incoming request times out.

In this case, you don't show what content-type you're sending with the POST, but Express has some built-in middleware you can use for several types:

```
// middleware to read body, parse it and place results in req.body
app.use(express.json());             // for application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded());       // for application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You just make sure the appropriate middleware is either part of your request handler or is installed before it.

If your particular POST here was a form post direct from the browser, it would be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you could do either this:

```
// install application/x-www-form-urlencoded middleware for all
// request handlers that are defined after this one
app.use(express.urlencoded()); 

app.post("/hi",(req, res)=>{  ... }
```

or this:

```
// use application/x-www-form-urlencoded middleware for this
// one request handler
app.post("/hi", express.urlencoded(), (req, res)=>{
```

You can see the various types of content parsing middleware that Express has available [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express).

Comment: For me it wasn't enough to parse with either `express.json()` / `express.urlencoded()` or with `body-parser` + `.json()`. What really was able to get an output in my POST was using `req.query`. Hope ths could help, I'm still learning

Answer (score 1):

So for others like me who have been searching for a while make sure that the type of post request sent is application/json  for example I was using postman and by default it was set to text for body when i changed it to json it worked fine.