# Why cant I access req.body parameters in Node.js (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have problem with accessing parameters in another file in Javascript.
I have controller for adding content and uploading files to server.

Here is code where I call upload function and then create content.

```
async post(req, res) {
    try {
      await upload(req, res)
      .then(() => {
      const uploadsFileNames = [];
      const uploadsMimeTypes = [];
      const uploadsPath = [];

      let actualDate = new Date();
      let formatedDate = moment(actualDate).format(
        "DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm:ss"
      );
      
      Content.create({
        creationDate: formatedDate,
        dateRange: req.body.dateRange,
        sourceContent: req.body.sourceContent,
        outputContent: req.body.outputContent,
        selfGovernmentName: req.body.selfGovernmentName,
        createdBy: req.body.createdBy
      })
        .then((result) => {
          newContentId = result.id;
          creationDate = formatedDate;
          sourceContent = result.sourceContent;
          outputContent = result.outputContent;
          dateRange = result.dateRange,
          selfGovernmentName = result.selfGovernmentName;
          createdBy = result.createdBy;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({
            error: "Nepodarilo sa pridať obsah z dôvodu: ",
            err,
          });
        })
        .then(async () => {
          const checkId = Content.findOne({ where: {id: newContentId }});

          if (checkId == null) {
                res.status(400).send({ message: 'Obsah so zadaným ID sa nenašiel.'});
                return;
            }

          for(let i=0;i<req.files.length;i++){
            uploadsFileNames.push(req.files[i].filename);
            uploadsMimeTypes.push(req.files[i].mimetype);
            uploadsPath.push(req.files[i].destination);
            ContentAttachment.create({
                fileName: uploadsFileNames[i],
                mimeType: uploadsMimeTypes[i],
                contentId: newContentId,
                path: uploadsPath[i],
            })
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500)
        })
        .then(() => {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: "Obsah bol úspešne pridaný.",
          });
        })
      })
      .catch((callback) => {
        res.status(400).send(callback); 
    })
    
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500);
    }
  },
```

Here is whole upload.js file.

```
const util = require("util");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const moment = require("moment");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const process = require("process");
const fs = require("fs");

const formatedDate = moment(Date.now()).format(
    "DD-MM-YYYY_HH-mm-ss"
    );

const maxSize = 500000;

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    const selfGovernment = 'Bratislava';
    const week = 'druhy az treti';

    var dir1 = path.join(`${__dirname}/../../uploads/${selfGovernment}`);
    var dir2 = path.join(`${__dirname}/../../uploads/${selfGovernment}/${week}`);

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir1)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir1, { recursive: true });
    }
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir2)){
      fs.mkdirSync(dir2, { recursive: true });
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(dir1)) {
      if (fs.existsSync(dir2)){
        callback(null, path.join(`${__dirname}/../../uploads/${selfGovernment}/${week}`));
    }
    } else {
        console.log('Directory not found.');
    }
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const fileSize = parseInt(req.headers["content-length"]);

    const match = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "application/pdf", "application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"];
    if (match.indexOf(file.mimetype) === -1) {
      console.log(file)
      var message = `${file.originalname} je chybný súbor. Odosielajte iba png/jpeg/jpg alebo pdf/doc.`;
      return callback(message, null);
    }
    else if(fileSize > maxSize){
        console.log(file)
        var tooLargeMessage = `${file.originalname} je chybný súbor. Odosielajte súbory do 5MB.`;
        return callback(tooLargeMessage, null);
    }  

    //var filename = crypto.randomUUID();
    var newName = slugify(file.originalname);
      var filename = `${formatedDate}_${newName}`;
      callback(null, filename);
    }
});

var uploadFiles = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: maxSize } }).array("multi-files", 4);
var uploadFilesMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFiles);

module.exports = uploadFilesMiddleware;
```

Problem is that I want to send from first component selfGovernmentName and week from req.body. and use it in upload to create new folder with that name.

How can I achieve that? I tried everything, I was searching on internet but found nothing.
Weird for me is that when I console log req.body as first thing in try block, I get empty object. But when I run my code like this, it will work and upload files and also create content in database, but I don't want to have name and week hardcoded there.

Thanks

Edit + whole upload.js file and post function:

I am calling post from routes.js.

```
const ContentAttachmentController = require("../controllers/ContentAttachmentController");

app.post("/api/v1/content/attachments",
    ContentAttachmentController.post
);
```

Here is server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const config = require("./src/config/config");
const { sequelize } = require('./src/models');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['set-cookie']
  }));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cookieParser());

require("./src/routes/routes")(app);

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen(config.app_port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is up and running at port: ${config.app_port}`);
    });
});
```

When I send request from postman, it will upload files, create Content in Database and assing uploaded files to that content by ID.

Everything is working for me when I provide hard coded name and date for folder. I need to give these two parameters from Controller file to Upload.js middleware.

req.body cannot be empty if I am able to create content.

I am using multer for uploading files to server.

Comment: We're missing code context.  Please show where `post()` is called from and what middleware you're using with it.  Please show the `upload()` function.  Do you have appropriate middleware installed and configured that reads the body of the request to populate `req.body`?  Please it's entirely unclear what your multer code has to do with anything here as there don't appear to be any references to it in your code.

Comment: Wild guess since you don't show enough code, but the usual reason for an empty `req.body` is [Why is  req.body undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148975/why-is-req-body-undefined/70149330#70149330).

Comment: I edited whole question, added whole post function, added whole upload.js file, added server.js and added route. Hope that is everything

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem. It is funny, but problem was because in postman I was sending first file and then content. I change order, first I send content and then I send file and it is working now